# Testing with okhttp and new Spring 6 http interfaces

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okhttp, spring-test, spring-webclient

What's the best way to write integration tests that uses the new Spring 6 http interfaces with a mock server? Example:

```
@Bean
Blah configService() {

    var client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .defaultStatusHandler(HttpStatusCode::is4xxClientError, resp -> Mono.empty())
            .build();
    var proxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(client)).build();
    return proxyFactory.createClient(Blah.class);
}
```

```
interface BlahService {
    @GetExchange("/ok")
    ResponseEntity<Blah> getBlah();
}
```

basically trying to discover a reasonable way to use the mock server from okhttp (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientIntegrationTests.java)

with the `server.url` as a property I can inject the value and use it in test env as base url in my WebClient config.

Thanks.

I can't find anything specific on the web on this topic yet.

Comment: See https://github.com/gtiwari333/flowable-bpmn-vacation-request-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/flowabledemo/config/TestAppConfig.java

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `@DynamicPropertySource` to inject that property in your test class like so

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("server.url", () -> "http://localhost:" + mockWebServer.getPort());
}
```